# How to stop HTML elements from inheriting backgrounds in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble getting IE to not display a background of a child element when the parent has a background applied with a filter. I'm pretty new to using filters in CSS for IE. Here's a pseudo code example. HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item With Background</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Item Without Background</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a9db80', endColorstr='#96c56f',GradientType=0 );
}
ul ul {
    background: none;
}
ul ul li {
    background: none;
}
```

In this case, the child li element is inheriting the background filter from the parent. I can't seem to get the background to disappear. Do I maybe need to set the filter to something like none or transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [overriding the filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
ul ul {
    background: none;
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)" !important;
}
ul ul li {
    background: none;
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)" !important;
}
```